# Papaparse adds an extra field named __parsed_extra

Tags: javascript, papaparse

Let's say we've got some csv from our client and wanna parse it. For each row Papaparse adds extra field (as an array). How can we investigate the reason or tell Papaparse to skip extras? Once the line is not empty so it doesn't make sense to set `skipEmptyLines: true` up
Of cuz papaparse reports it in the errors section so we are not able to continue our process